# How to install jupyter lab on linux mint?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, linux-mint

I have installed pip3 by `sudo apt install python3-pip`

And then `pip3 install jupyterlab`

During installation errors:

> ERROR: jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2 has requirement pygments<3,>=2.4.1,
> but you'll have pygments 2.3.1 which is incompatible. ERROR: nbconvert
> 6.4.2 has requirement pygments>=2.4.1, but you'll have pygments 2.3.1 which is incompatible.
>
> WARNING: The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot
> are installed in '/home/swaraj/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress
> this warning, use --no-warn-script-location

At last it displays

> Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.0 Send2Trash-1.8.0 anyio-3.5.0
> argon2-cffi-21.3.0 argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0 asttokens-2.0.5.....

And when I'm executing jupyter lab it displays

```
Command 'jupyter' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install jupyter-core
```

Comment: you should try as per the suggestion:-  sudo apt install jupyter-core

Comment: @shamnadsherief I installed it, now it displays Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.

Comment: @shamnadsherief export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" this command was in other answer and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to install Jupyterlab (Desktop) on Mint 20.3, just go to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop then download the Ubuntu linux installer, install the libgtk-3-dev package with "sudo aptitude install libgtk-3-dev" and run "sudo gdebi JupyterLab-Setup-Debian.deb"
Hope this helps.
ES

PS: here is my config given by "$hostnamectl"
Static hostname: erwan-Latitude-E6420
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop
Machine ID: 09143d0261be487380a9ec9bf41d5922
Boot ID: 8e00c5a118284de3b078eaa213ae37f2
Operating System: Linux Mint 20.3
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-91-generic
Architecture: x86-64